# Why are the Keras and Orange VGG16 outputs different and how to fix it?

Tags: keras, vgg-net, orange

I'm optimizing some work I did moving from Orange to Python code, but I'm having some problems with image Embedders.
I'm trying to recreate my work using Tensorflow/Keras, but the outputs of the VGG16 networks but the 4096 outputs of the activation layer of the penultimate FC layer for this architecture, using Orange and Keras, are different.

[In the Orange documentation it is written:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Kya.png)

For python:

```
model_vgg = VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', pooling=None, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

model_vgg16 = Model(inputs=model_vgg.input, outputs=model_vgg.layers[-2].output)
```

[Keras VGG16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31umC.png)

To reshape some images to 224x244 pixels i use the same package and code of function load_image_or_none  -> https://github.com/biolab/orange3-imageanalytics/blob/master/orangecontrib/imageanalytics/utils/embedder_utils.py

And get the same image resized to 224x224 used for VGG16 in Orange, by widget Save Image.
[My resized images and Orange images are the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBO7o.png)

Perhaps I'm making a mistake during preprocessing, since in the Orange documentation it is written that they use the original weights of the model.

To preprocess the images i try the Keras preprocess_input of VGG16, and manually

```
def process_vgg16(imgs):
  output = np.zeros(imgs.shape)

  VGG_MEAN = np.array([103.939, 116.779, 123.68], dtype=np.float32)
  for i in range(0, imgs.shape[0]):

    b = np.array(imgs[i,:,:,2], dtype=np.float32)
    g = np.array(imgs[i,:,:,1], dtype=np.float32)
    r = np.array(imgs[i,:,:,0], dtype=np.float32)

    output[i,:,:,0] = b - VGG_MEAN[0]
    output[i,:,:,1] = g - VGG_MEAN[1]
    output[i,:,:,2] = r - VGG_MEAN[2]

    #output = output/255
    return output
```

Note: The images are in gray scale, so all channels are the same.

Results:

[First three output of an image in orange (VGG16)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jex5Z.png)

[First three output of an image in Keras (VGG16)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T29ph.png)

Would anyone know the reason?